# htaccess redirect entire site to one directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

What I want to do is very simple but cant find the unique solution anywhere. I want to redirect all files and folders in the site to a single directory.

Redirect domain.com/ and domain.com/* to domain.com/folder/

Basically all strings typed into the url is redirected to the subfolder hiding the entire site from the public and redirecting to a splash page with the condition of ![ip address]

Comment: What do you mean by condition of ![ip address] ?

Comment: sound like a temporal 'under maintenance' redirect? Is this what you want?